# How to create an IAM role and associate it with the service account for a Kubernetes pod in the same manifest file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have setup an IAM OIDC provider in my EKS cluster, and have used it to manually assign IAM roles to Kubernetes Pods.

For the pipeline for my Kubernetes pod however, I want to have it automatically create and update the IAM role for the pod as part of the normal application pipeline.  This makes it easy to update the IAM permissions as your application needs to interact with more services over time.

Does anyone know of a way to create an IAM role with a service operator and associate with a pod in a manifest file?  I've searched all day and it doesn't look like it can be done.

The only alternative I can think of is creating the IAM role in a different pipeline/workflow, which would work but would make updating the IAM role with new permissions frustrating, as you would have to coordinate the ordering of deployment between the two pipelines.

Comment: You have failed to specify anything about your "pipeline," including whether it already has the necessary IAM role to create/update other roles, what technology it is using, whether it is running inside your kubernetes cluster, what experiments you have already tried that did not work as you wished, and in general any specifics that would make this question answerable versus a "thought experiment."

Comment: Perhaps this blog entry could help.They are setting up k8s service accounts with iam roles. 

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/